# Three.js OBJMTLLoader load maps from .mtl only in Safari

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've created a server with express.js and I'm trying to load a model:

```
(new THREE.OBJMTLLoader()).load('/coffee/models/alexia.obj', '/coffee/models/alexia.mtl',   function(object) {
  return scene.add(object);
});
```

But this works only in Safari (my OS by the way - Mac OS X Mavericks). Chrome, Opera, Firefox don't load texture only black object. As I can see I'm not the only person who faced with this problem but I couldn't find out the answer.

Comment: Do you have an animation loop, or are you only calling `renderer.render()` once?

Comment: I have a simple animation loop: 
animate = function() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    return requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  };